# Self Hosted Website www redirect to non www

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, self-hosting

I am self hosting a website on a Synology NAS. I have set up an SSL certificate, set up the DNS records on Google Domains. If I enter the website, andrewr.ca, into a browser it works fine. If I enter [www.andrewr.ca](http://www.andrewr.ca) it does not work and the SSL is not valid. I am trying to figure out how to fix this issue but get stuck every time. I have a .htaccess file that looks like this:

[image]

And my Google Domains account looks like this. [enter image description

[image]

My SSL cert looks like this:

[image]

Could someone please point me in the right direction here. I just want to be able to enter [www.andrewr.ca](http://www.andrewr.ca) and it works the exact same as if I enter andrewr.ca

I have tried changing the CNAME, changing the .htaccess and also adding a different SSL certificate but had no luck with anything I try so far.

Comment: There is no way to really fix this on protocol level. If you SSL certificate is _not_ valid for "www.example.com", then there simply is no way to redirect to "example.com" in a clean way without all modern browser's refusing to follow that redirection. Reason is security and that does make sense, once you think about it. The only clean solution is to get an additional SSL certificate for the "www" variant of the domain, or, much easier, to add that variant to the existing domain, so that the certificate is valid for _both_ host names. That is possible with let's encrypt certificates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This honestly probably has two separated answers out there for you to find, but I am posting this just because it's a solution we use currently in our setup to rewrite `non https` to `https` AND `non www` to `www` in one swoop.  These are the rewrite directives in my production `.htaccess`

```
#SSL  = 1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]


# Redirect www and http to https - non-www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This is not for everyone and ONLY works if you have a single domain in your setup -- Which the top two lines of the htacces file there are put there to deal with multiple domains on the single files set to canonicalize the domain ..  Once you have multiple domains in there .. You WILL NEED a separated SSL for each domain, AND the `www` for it to work .. But as for a SINGLE domain, this will forward to `https - non www` without the need for a secondary SSL on the `www`

Comment: Dude, thank you so much! So much trouble in the past week trying to figure this out.